# Shift array down by one in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am having some trouble getting a function I have been writing to work properly. I need it to take an array that is sized 1 to x, and transfer it to a new array which is sized 0 to x-1. I would think it would work just like this:

```
Private Function ShiftDownArray(theArray() As String) As String()
Dim a As Integer


ReDim ShiftDownArray(LBound(theArray) - 1 To UBound(theArray) - 1)

For a = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)

    ShiftDownArray(a - 1) = theArray(a)

Next a


End Function
```

But I get a compile error: Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object. The documentation on this error essentially says delete that line to make it work, which doesn't point me in the right direction. I have tried changing the type to variant, but it starts a chain reaction of needing to change array type from string to variant, and it leads to issues in other parts of my program.

Is there any way to approach this that will allow me to retain the string array type? Thanks

Comment: when you say sized 1 to X and move to an array of size 0 to x-1, do you mean an array of one slot smaller (removing the first/last thing) or same sized slot (also removing the first/last thing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
Public Sub ShiftArrayTest()
    'Make an 1-bound array
    Dim arr1() As String, N As Long, i As Long
    N = 10
    ReDim arr1(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        arr1(i) = CStr(i)
    Next i


    'Now for the shift
    Dim arr2() As String

    arr2 = ShiftArray(arr1)

End Sub

Public Function ShiftArray(ByRef theArray() As String) As String()
    'Now for the shift
    Dim i1 As Long, N As Long, i As Long, res() As String
    i1 = LBound(theArray): N = UBound(theArray) - i1 + 1
    ReDim res(0 To N - 1)
    For i = 0 To N - 1
        res(i) = theArray(i1 + i)
    Next i
    ShiftArray = res
End Function
```

What I am doing here is taking any array and converting it into a 0-bound array.

Comment: This answer actually helped me the most before you edited it. Essentially what it helped me to realize is that although these restrictions on passing arrays are impossible to get around, I can just not use a function. It works just fine if I don't try to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arrays of most types as a `Variant` between methods and procedures in VBA

```
Private Function ShiftDownArray(ByRef theArray As Variant) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim x(0 To UBound(theArray) - 1) As Variant

    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        x(i) = theArray(i + 1)
    Next i

    ShiftDownArray = x

End Function
```

But more importantly - why would you want to do this anyway? You can just -/+ 1 to the index in the original array?

Comment: The source array is normally 0 to x... in this method I am creating an array from a collection with toArray, which automatically makes the dimensions 1 to x..

Comment: Does that still happen if you explicitly declare `Option Base 0` at the top of the module?

Comment: Interesting... I will have to try that out. I didn't know it was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is most probably in this line: 'ReDim ShiftDownArray(LBound(theArray) - 1 To UBound(theArray) - 1)'

It looks like you're recursively calling itself, which seems odd given there isn't a base case.

See the following example as provided by this [website](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/useful-array-functions-for-vba-part-6/). The gist of it is that it will skip the first element and copy everything over 'to the left'.

```
Function Array_Shift(arr As Variant) As Variant
' http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

  Dim tempArray As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  tempArray = arr

  ' shift elements one position up
  ' by skipping the first element of the source array
  For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray) - 1
    tempArray(i) = tempArray(i + 1)
  Next i

  ' remove last element
  ' which is now empty
  ReDim Preserve tempArray(LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray) - 1)

  Array_Shift = tempArray

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The trouble is not with passing an array of strings as a parameter - you can pass arrays of any type, as far as I'm aware.  However, assigning a value to `ShiftDownArray(a - 1)` is ambiguous as you could be accessing the a-1th element of the array or passing `a - 1` as a parameter to the `ShiftDownArray()` function.

The `Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object.` error message hints to this.  You are calling the `ShiftDownArray()` function rather than accessing the array.  The compiler knows you are going to assign something to the value returned by the function (because it is followed by an `=`) but doesn't know the type as it hasn't yet evaluated `theArray(a)`.  To ensure that the assignment can complete regardless of the type of `theArray(a)`, the compiler tries to make sure that `ShiftDownArray()` returns a `Variant` or `Object` to which anything can be assigned.

To avoid this error you can create a temporary array which can be accessed in the conventional manner and assign that array to `ShiftDownArray` to return from the function.

The following code shows this:

```
Private Function ShiftDownArray(theArray() As String) As String()

    ReDim tempArray(LBound(theArray) - 1 To UBound(theArray) - 1) As String

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
        tempArray(i) = theArray(i + 1)
    Next i

    ShiftDownArray = tempArray

End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't useful, could you please provide some additional feedback? Thanks

Comment: I didn't down-vote it, but I am guessing that it is because it is exactly what I have already, and won't work, either. You can only pass arrays as variants, not strings.

Comment: Thanks, although the problem is not passing an array of strings.  I have updated my post to explain further.